# Apache httpd server on windows won't start

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, trac, bitnami

I installed Apache on Windows7 through a bitnami install package for trac. As a final installation step the installer tried to start the Apache httpd service and threw up an error that starting the https service failed.

I found out why when I tried to start httpd from command prompt and got this error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 564 of F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
SetEnv takes 1-2 arguments, an environment variable name and optional value to pass to CGI.
```

Here is the offending line:

```
SetEnv PATH "${PATH};F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin;"
```

I changed it to this:

```
SetEnv PATH "F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin;"
```

and the service started.

My questions are:

1) What is the syntax/language used in the httpd.conf file?

2) How would one have to change that line to make it compile and preserve the original intent of appending `F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin` to the environment variable `PATH`?

3) Assuming this works on some platforms why would it not work on Windows?

Thanks.

**Update**

Like the responses say the issue *was* with `PATH`. However the fact that there are spaces in the paths doesn't appear to be the issue. Not only that I isolated the path in PATH that was causing the problem. It was this `"C:\tools\mkstools"`, exactly like that. I got rid of the quotes and that enabled httpd to start. So I'm still scratching my head. Why would the quotes cause the problem?

Comment: Is `PATH` the system path, perhaps retrieved using [PassEnv](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#passenv)? You may need to both [quote and escape](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/apache/users/436195) any whitespace.

Comment: Hi, Bitnami developer here. I tried to reproduce your issue but I haven't been able, the installation went fine. It seems that there was an issue with the PATH variable of your system, did you modify it before? You can check the content of it running `set PATH` in a command prompt or acccessing to
Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: @RjOllos Yes it is and I was able to confirm that is the problem. And yes you are right again, I used quotes around all the paths with spaces and that doesn't fix it by itself. How do you escape whitespace in Windows? Thanks.

Comment: So I guess that `"${PATH};F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin;"` is expanded to something like `"C:\path\to\a;"C:\tools\mkstools";C:\path\to\b;F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin;"` and it's probably treated as 3 arguments to `SetEnv`: `"C:\path\to\a;"`, `C:\tools\mkstools` and `";C:\path\to\b;F:/Bitnami/trac-1.0.9-0/apache2/bin;"`. I'm not sure how quoted paths should be handled. I would probably look into whether they can be escaped or [encoded](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#functions). You might want to ask on the [Apache mailing list](http://httpd.apache.org/lists.html).

Answer (score 4):

For me, it worked by replacing `${PATH}` with `%PATH%`.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you!